# flutter not showing devices in VS code and flutter commands also not working

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-test

I face this problem after every 2,3 days that VS code doesn't show devices even they don't show chrome or edge. Then I run flutter commands but flutter commands are also not working. no error, no output in CMD. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: your vscode not opened as admin I think, You can restart the vscode and try.

Comment: Run flutter doctor and add the output in your question.

Comment: For the devices not showing up, try enabling the [Flutter Daemon log](https://dartcode.org/docs/logging/#flutter-daemon) for the VS code extension and see whether it records any errors. If `flutter` isn't working from the terminal, you need to ensure the `bin` folder inside the Flutter SDK is in your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by an extension.
This was how I solved my mine
just search for the extension uninstall or disable it.
Restart your vscode again.
Happy coding